# java hibernate 4 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, exception, jakarta-ee

I'm learning Java EE and Hibernate, and I've run into the following problem:

I've created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse, I've converted it into a MAVEN project, added the mysql-connector-java and the hibernate-core dependencies to the pom.xml.
I've added a servlet, and in the doGet method, I've tried  to initialize the sessionfactory to create the tables. I'm using tomcat.

When I'm making a request to the servlet I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found:   org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect
 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:77)
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:65)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:146)
org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1818)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1776)
hu.adamsan.testhibernate.TestHibernate.doGet(TestHibernate.java:74)
```

pom.xml:

```
dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've tried to look into the Maven Dependencies, org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.class is in there, in the location: getServletContext().getRealPath(".") ->E:\eclips_jee\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\TestHibernateWeb\
, in the WEB-INF\lib directory, there is hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar, when I opened it with 7zip, I could find inside the org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect.class.

What am I missing? I really have no idea.

doGet method:

```
    PrintWriter w = response.getWriter();
    w.println("Testing hibernate<br/>");
    w.println(getServletContext().getRealPath(".")+"<br/>");

    Configuration config;
    ServiceRegistry registry;
    SessionFactory factory;     
    config = new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(Modell.class);       
    Properties props = getProperties();     
    props.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create");      
    config.setProperties(props);        
    registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(props).buildServiceRegistry();        
    factory = config.buildSessionFactory(registry);     
    factory.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the question. You've found `MySQLDialect` and `MySQL5Dialect` in your jar files, but your configuration file tries to use `MYSQLDialect`. Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: So, basically, I've typed big 'y' instead of small 'y'. I'm embarrassed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm puting this because the above answer wasn't accurate for me, In my case I'm using Intellij IDEA While working with Hibernate dependency I was over configuring the pom dependency with a type (pom type) My solution is to remove that type.

```
<!--        Hibernate JPA dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

The working version Is :

```
<!--        Hibernate JPA dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**NO POM TYPE**

Which allowed to make ride of the following bug :

**java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.hibernate.SessionFactory not present**
that generally was blocking the resolve of the following property
`<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>`
and thus while doing the setup of hibernate session factory under the spring framework