# Hibernate, Spring, some error with propertyConfigurator

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, propertyconfigurator

I have some Spring context configuration

```
<bean name="propertyConfigurator" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location" value="classpath:/com/net/model/jdbc.properties"/>
</bean>
            ....

<bean id="sessionFactoryToBillingDb" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            ....
```

**jdbc.properties** is look like

```
...
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
...
```

And i want to use HQL console from Inellij Idea, but get error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialectt.MySQLDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

org.hibernate.dialect.**MySQLDialectt.MySQLDialect** 
What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java hibernate 4 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206441/java-hibernate-4-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-dialect-class-not-found-org)

Comment: As per the duplicate: The class is named: "MySQLDialect", you have a typo there (Dialectt)

Comment: i can't undestand how hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect seted into  jdbc.properties convert into org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialectt.MySQLDialect in hql console

Comment: Did you try printing the content of ${hibernate.dialect}? (e.G. put it in a place where a number is expected and see what happens). Did you make a full text search through your project for the text "MySQLDialect"?

Comment: Do other properties from jdbc.properties get carried along correct?

Comment: if i put instead ${hibernate.dialect} org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect all works fine, but through properties have error "Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialectt.MySQLDialect]"

Comment: yes all other properties works correct

Comment: If you put the content from the properties file (org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect) instead does it still work? (note the '5').

Comment: yes, it still work ( <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop> )

Comment: Get "Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialectt.MySQL5Dialect]"  if i use ${hibernate.dialect} variable

Answer (score 1):

You added an extra t. That's what the error message says:

Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialectt.MySQLDialect]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the property has a different value (`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialectt.MySQLDialect`) than you suspect it to have (`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`). So something must change that value and this something is not in the portion of the project you show us.

I know this from what we have tried in the comments of the question:

1. Write the actual value there instead of the parameter: Works, so its not Hibernate doing it wrong
2. Test if other parameters from the file are used: Works, so the file reading is working properly.

Things you should try:

1. You need to print out the value `${hibernate.dialect}`. The easiest way to do so is to use the parameter at the wrong place (e.G. where the url belongs or similar). That causes you to see the error message there and you can be certain what the actual value of that variable is.
2. You should do a full text search of your Project for the patterns "MySQL", "Dialectt" and "Dialect" and see if you find anything that could cause this.
3. If that fails, start a new project that consists ONLY of the element needed to recreate this specific problem and nothing(!) else. See if it works there, if so start merging this project into your current one until it works -> Then you have found where its gone wrong.